# I am having trouble in if-elif statements in python

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
import random

lst = ['1', '2', '3', '4']


if lst.index('1') == 0 or lst.index('2') == 0:
    print("The number is in index 0")
elif lst.index('1') == 1 or lst.index('2') == 1:
    print("The number is in index 1")
elif lst.index('1') == 2 or lst.index('2') == 2:
    print("The number is in index 2")
elif lst.index('1') == 3 or lst.index('2') == 3:
    print("The number is in index 3")
```

And here's my output:
The number is in index 0

I want to know that why is it not printing the index of '2'? It is printing the index of '1' only.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try not to use titles like "I'm getting error" because they say very little about what the issue is. Try to use a more descriptive title, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65698658/edit) your question

Comment: You use `elif`. After one condition is satisfied the others aren't checked anymore.

Comment: because `if lst.index('1') == 0` is true. And there are no *errors*, but rather an unwanted behavior (AKA bug)

Comment: If 1st condition is satisfied in `if-elif` clause, it will never executed branches below. Read about [how if-else works](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

lst = ['1', '2', '3', '4']


if lst.index('1') == 0 or lst.index('2') == 0:
    print("The number is in index 0")
if lst.index('1') == 1 or lst.index('2') == 1:
    print("The number is in index 1")
if lst.index('1') == 2 or lst.index('2') == 2:
    print("The number is in index 2")
if lst.index('1') == 3 or lst.index('2') == 3:
    print("The number is in index 3")
```

Since you are using elif once the if condition is true, it wont go to elif statements. In In above code it will check all the if statements and both the 1st and 3rd if statements are printed

Answer (score 0):

Since you have placed them in if-elif formation it will iterate through them one by one and if anyone of them is satisfying it wont print others. Since you have place

```
if lst.index('1') == 0 or lst.index('2') == 0:
    print("The number is in index 0")
```

in the beginning and it is True the code will end after printing the result. If you want all the correct results you should instead use this:

```
if lst.index('1') == 0 or lst.index('2') == 0:
    print("The number is in index 0")
if lst.index('1') == 1 or lst.index('2') == 1:
    print("The number is in index 1")
if lst.index('1') == 2 or lst.index('2') == 2:
    print("The number is in index 2")
if lst.index('1') == 3 or lst.index('2') == 3:
    print("The number is in index 3")
```